# How to use controller injection in opentaps 1.5.0?

Tags: crm, opentaps

I'm a few days new into opentaps, and I've been trying to add a menu item of an entity I created to the crm/sfa application tabs. Since almost no documentation exists on how to achieve this progress is slow. However I did come across [this article](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/Customizing_opentaps_Applications#Controller_Injection) and I've tried injecting my controller and the example controller into the app but so far gotten nowhere. Can anyone clarify this actually works as is documented and perhaps provide pointers as to how to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this works and following the docs you should be able to use it. Please note that you can only inject one controller and not more than that. We created a patch which allows multiple controller injection and if you are interested I can send it to you.

Comment: Yes please. Although I'm far along development now that I have essentially "bricked" my modifications into crmsfa.

Comment: To be honest with you it is the best way.  If you abuse the controller injection your code will become difficult to read and difficult to maintain. The new release of opentas will be completely different so it is ok for you to update the code inside each module

Comment: We're already committed to the 1.5 unfortunately and have to stick with that for the forseeable future.